# Setting cookies for multiple sub-domains

Tags: http, cookies, https, subdomain, cross-domain

Is it possible to set a cookie for *http://www.example.com* from a PHP file located at *https://secure.example.com*? I have some code that was given to me, that appears to try and fails at this. I was wondering if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Webpages can only set cookies for the second (or higher) level domain that they belong to.

This means that `secure.example.com` can read and set cookies for `secure.example.com` or `.example.com`, the latter of which can also be read and set by `www.example.com`

One last note:  If the secure flag is set on a cookie, it can only be read and set over an https connection.

Comment: Hi @Powerlord, does that mean I can use the Javascript on secure.example.com to set a cookie for .example.com too? By just changing the value for `document.cookie`? Thx

Comment: @Louis_PIG I don't have a lot of experience dealing with cookies in JavaScript.  I would think you'd be able to do that, though... as I recall, it's part of the Cookie standard.

Comment: Thanks @Powerlord . I am dealing with some problem like this, but your answer at least confirmed that this should be possible. Thanks!

Comment: So if you own a.example and b.example.com but nothing else .example.com then this isn't a viable solution...

Comment: This won't work on www-less domains tho `https://example.com`

Answer (score 5):

If you set the cookie domain to ".example.com", the cookie will work for all subdomains.

Comment: I wondering if I could be specific to which domains the cookie is sent to.

Comment: @nilacqua: No. If the cookie is set for .example.com, it will be visible for any subdomain of example.com

Comment: Would this work for all subsub domains as well. Like would .example.com work on sub.example.com and sub.sub.example.com? Or would you have to do .sub.example.com to make that work?