# Sub domain cookie security

Tags: cookies

Very simple question here. Knowing about cross domain cookie security, does the same apply to sub domains?

EG. Should I be able to read a cookie set on some.abc123.com from the sub domain of www.abc123.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookie domains are suffix matching, so cookies of `www.abc123.com` will not be sent on the site of `some.abc123.com` and visa versa.

To have cookies be sent on both domains you should use `.abc123.com` as the domain.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative set a cookie at the abc123.com level then set and read cookies from there.

see here 
[Setting cookies for multiple sub-domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465036/setting-cookies-for-multiple-sub-domains)