# Setting cookie in Angular app and passing it to another subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to set a cookie from my angular app in one subdomain, (`app1.example.com`) and then pass the cookie to another subdomain (`app2.example.com`) by doing a redirect. Is this possible? Below is how I am setting the cookie in my `app1`.

```
document.cookie = “mycookie=myvalue; path=/; domain=example.com”
```

Comment: Look here for your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465036/setting-cookies-for-multiple-sub-domains